# VB2012 FormatException was unhandled , String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The DateTimePicker1 will not be read but the other function will be read.I would like to know what is the problem in this code.

```
Public com As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
Public da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
Public dr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
Public dt As New DataTable
Public ds As DataSet

Private Sub frmupdateaccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim READER As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String

    con.Open()

    query = "Select * from user_tbl where userid='" & txtuserid.Text & "'"
    com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(query, con)

    READER = com.ExecuteReader

    While READER.Read

        txtcontactnumber.Text = READER.GetString("contactnumber")
        cbxgender.Text = READER.GetString("gender")
        datetimepicker1.Text = READER.GetString("dateofbirth")

    End While

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This happens when you think that a date is a string. This is not true. What is the value of the field "dateofbirth" in the database? What is its datatype? What is your locale settings "dd/MM/yyyy" or something else? I repeat, dates are not strings and when you treat them as strings strange things happens when automatic conversion kicks in

Comment: By the way, if one of you users is malicious enough to [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) you are in deep troubles

Comment: datetimepicker1.Text = READER.GetDateTime("dateofbirth") - Thanks Steve~